# c# Fingerprint biometrics, UserConsentVerificationResult() no response (WPF)

Tags: c#, windows-10, biometrics

I'm trying to use the WIN10 api in WPF, to authenticate users.
I'm using the sample code from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/fingerprint-biometrics) :

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> RequestConsent(string userMessage)
{
    string returnMessage;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userMessage))
    {
        userMessage = "Please provide fingerprint verification.";
    }

    try
    {
        // Request the logged on user's consent via fingerprint swipe.
        var consentResult = await Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerifier.RequestVerificationAsync(userMessage);

        switch (consentResult)
        {
            case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.Verified:
                returnMessage = "Fingerprint verified.";
                break;
            case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.DeviceBusy:
                returnMessage = "Biometric device is busy.";
                break;
            case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.DeviceNotPresent:
                returnMessage = "No biometric device found.";
                break;
            case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.DisabledByPolicy:
                returnMessage = "Biometric verification is disabled by policy.";
                break;
            case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.NotConfiguredForUser:
                returnMessage = "The user has no fingerprints registered. Please add a fingerprint to the " +
                                "fingerprint database and try again.";
                break;
            case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.RetriesExhausted:
                returnMessage = "There have been too many failed attempts. Fingerprint authentication canceled.";
                break;
            case Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerificationResult.Canceled:
                returnMessage = "Fingerprint authentication canceled.";
                break;
            default:
                returnMessage = "Fingerprint authentication is currently unavailable.";
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        returnMessage = "Fingerprint authentication failed: " + ex.ToString();
    }

    return returnMessage;
}
```

The `CheckAvailabilityAsync()` is working fine. 
The `RequestVerificationAsync()` calls the api and the modal dialog is shown, but after authentication the modal dialog disappears and the application is still waiting for result... 
Also tried building the app and running it as administrator, but still no results. 
I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In the method call try this, it worked for me

```
var res = RequestConsent("Please provide fingerprint verification.").Result;
```